# LibGDX - how to detect touchUp with GestureListener?

Tags: java, libgdx, touch

I'm making a game and I have implemented GestureListener as my inputprocessor. It came with a bunch of methods such as fling, pan, tap etc etc including touchDown. However, there is no touchUp method!

What I want to do is have something happen when the user does a 'fling', but I want something to happen when the user then takes their finger off the screen after flinging, probably setting a flinging boolean and testing if true when taking finger off the screen.

However, I don't see how I can get a touchUp method into my inputprocessor! Is there any work around to this or an alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx), you can see how to use the `touchUp`method that is in the `InputProcessor` interface with the `GestureListener` that you already implemented.

For what are you asking, it should be something like this:

```
public class Inputs implements ApplicationListener, GestureListener, InputProcessor {
    boolean isFling= false;

    //A lot of code with the GestureListener methods
    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        // do something...
        isFling = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(isFling) {
            isFling= false;
            // Do something when touchup trigger and fling finished
            doSomething();
        }
        return false;
    }
    // the rest of the methods
}
```

In the same link, you can learn how to manage a lot of inputs at the same time with the `InputMultiplexer`.

Hope this helps!